# How to put text at last in a setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, overwrite

I would like to put a text at last in  a function that uses `setInterval`, but I could not do that, the code is given below-

```
 function checkInIntervals(howManyTimes, howOften) 
 {
     var T = window.open("", "MsgWindow","width=400,height=600"); 
     var counter = 0; 
     var interval = setInterval(function() 
     { 
        T.document.title = 'MIKE!'; counter++; 
        if (counter === howManyTimes) 
        { 
            clearInterval(interval); 
        } 
        // do something 
        T.document.write('Where are you?'); 
        T.document.write("<br/>"); 
        console.log(counter, 'iteration'); 
     }, howOften)

    T.document.write('This text needs to be placed last.');//problem 
    T.document.write("<br/>");
    T.document.close(); // problem
}
checkInIntervals(3, 1000);
```

Here, `T.document.write('This text needs to be placed last.');` appears first, and disappears due to `T.document.close();`,  but I need 'This text needs to be placed last.' to appear at last, also, I need to have `T.document.close();` as I need new window each time I run the function without having previous text.

How can I do that?

Comment: because interval is asynchronous. The code would have to be inside the interval to be last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the things you want to do last in the if that checks the counter.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mvhL9ct2/1/

**JS:**

```js
function checkInIntervals(howManyTimes, howOften) {
  var T = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=400,height=600");
  var counter = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      T.document.title = 'MIKE!';
      counter++;
      // do something 
      T.document.write('Where are you?');
      T.document.write("<br/>");

      if (counter === howManyTimes) {
        T.document.write('This text needs to be placed last.');
        T.document.write("<br/>");
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

      console.log(counter, 'iteration');
    },
    howOften)

  T.document.close(); // problem
}
checkInIntervals(3, 1000);
```

Comment: Your code gives console errors and loops forever - you need to test if you are allowed to even open a window

Comment: that comes from jsfiddle.

Comment: Your JSFiddle also loops

Comment: Thanks, but could you make the title fixed? it does not appear first time, it appears when the loop starts,  we can write ``T.document.title = 'MIKE!';`` just after creating the window, but that makes it writing  two times, can we write one time and have the title all the time?

Comment: I would recommend you to use `appendChild` or any other alternative, less document.write. This method replaces all the existing html

Answer (score 0):

Text `T.document.write('This text needs to be placed last.')` appears first, because function passed to `setInterval` is not executes immediately. After `setTimeout` has been called execution continues and the next command after that function is `T.document.write('This text needs to be placed last.')`

To make this text last you should place it before `clearInterval` function

```
function checkInIntervals(howManyTimes, howOften) {
    var T = window.open("", "MsgWindow","width=400,height=600"); 
        var counter = 0; 
    var interval = setInterval(function() { 
      T.document.title = 'MIKE!'; counter++; 
      // do something 
      T.document.write('Where are you?'); 
      T.document.write("<br/>");

      if (counter === howManyTimes) { 
        T.document.write('This text needs to be placed last.'); 
        T.document.write("<br/>");
        clearInterval(interval);
        return; 
      } 

      console.log(counter, 'iteration'); }, 
    howOften)

    T.document.close(); // problem
}
checkInIntervals(3, 1000);
```

Comment: Still not 100% right, the message will still not be the last thing

Comment: Please check now